# SQL Dynamic columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
 select @cols =

                STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(grade)         
                from #temp        
                group by grade        

        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE        
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')         
    ,1,1,'')        

  select @colsRollup = STUFF((SELECT ', Sum(' + QUOTENAME(grade) + ') as '+QUOTENAME     (grade)        
                from #temp       
                group by grade        

        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE        
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')         
    ,1,1,'')    

  set @query    

      =      'SELECT * into #temp3 from 
             (
              SELECT lob as "Vertical", '+ @colsRollup + '       
              FROM        
                  (        
                    SELECT lob,' + @cols + ' from         
                        (        
                         select lob,        
                           grade,        
                           asso_count        
                           from #temp        
                         ) x         
                     pivot         
                          (        
                           count(grade)        
                           for grade in (' + @cols + ')        
                           ) p         
                  ) x1 
                    GROUP BY lob with ROLLUP)x2'        

         execute(@query)
```

I am trying to create dynamic columns and insert it into a temporary table. 
But it throws an error saying that #temp3 is not a valid object name. the code works if i dont try to insert the dynamic generated columns into a table.

Comment: mysql or sql-server ? Choose one and edit tags. (It looks like sql-server)

Comment: @prasanthunnikrishnan How are you executing this? In a stored procedure or some other way?

Comment: @jpw: Yup, Its being executed as a Stored Proc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute the code and then try to access the `#temp3`table like:

```
execute(@query)
select * from #temp3
```

I would think it will have gone out of scope, which would explain the error message.
You could try to modify your query to include a `SELECT`like:

```
SET @query = '
 SELECT * INTO #temp3 FROM
   (
   SELECT lob as "Vertical", '+ @colsRollup + '       
   FROM        
     (        
      SELECT lob,' + @cols + ' from (select lob, grade, asso_count from #temp) x
      PIVOT (count(grade) for grade in (' + @cols + ')) p         
      ) x1 
      GROUP BY lob with ROLLUP
     ) x2; SELECT * FROM #temp3'
```

Note how the last line now includes `; SELECT * FROM #temp3`

If you add that you should get the results back, if that is what you want.